# Getting the same coordinates for every address

Tags: r, google-api, maps, geocode

I ran the code below in R:

```
CLCLT_Homes <- file.choose(new = TRUE)
origAddress <- read.csv(CLCLT_Homes, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
geocoded <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
for (i in 1:nrow(origAddress))
{
  result <- geocode(origAddress$Address[i], output = "latlona", source = "google")
  origAddress$lon[1] <- as.numeric(result[1])
  origAddress$lat[1] <- as.numeric(result[2])
  origAddress$geoAddress[i] <- as.character(result[3])
}

write.csv(origAddress, "where I put the file.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

and when I went to look at the file, it had created columns for long and lat for every address, but each address had the exact same longitude and latitude (oddly, except for the address at the very top; it had its own coordinates while all others had different coordinates that matched).  Did I forget to include something in the code?  Is it only reading the first two lines correctly and then not rotating?

Comment: In every iteration of the `for` loop, `origAddress$lon[1] <- as.numeric(result[1])` will assign the geocoding result to the first element of `origAddress$lon`.  If I understand correctly, you'll want to change this to `origAddress$lon[i] <- as.numeric(result[1])`.  Same thing for `origAddress$lat`.

Comment: [This post](http://www.storybench.org/geocode-csv-addresses-r/) demonstrates the code you are using.  You should be able to spot the differences between your code and the post.

Comment: Thank you both, it's very obvious now.  I must have just been in zombie mode when I was writing that part.  Thank you again.